# Proving the Pigeonhole Principle using proof by contradiction

Tags: proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

Given that the Pigeonhole Principle states that "When n + 1 pigeons roost in n holes, there must be some hole containing at least two pigeons", prove this by contradiction.

how would one go about doing this without using a specific example

Comment: You want to prove the pigeonhole principle by contradiction. The contradiction of "there is some hole containing two pigeons" is "all holes contain at most one pigeon". Now, what can the total number of pigeons be if you assume the contradicted statement? If you can see why it cannot be $n+1$ then you have proved the PP by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you could fit $n + 1$ pigeons into $n$ holes without any hole containing at least two pigeons. Number the $n$ holes for which this is possible from $1$ to $n$, and let $a_i$ denote the number of pigeons in hole $i$. By assumption, each $a_i$ is either $0$ or $1$. Since every pigeon is in a hole, it must be the case that $a_1 + \cdots + a_n$ is the total number of pigeons. That is
$$
a_1 + \cdots + a_n = n + 1
$$
On the other hand, we have $a_i \leq 1$ for all $i$ (there is at most $1$ pigeon in each hole). Thus
$$
a_1 + \cdots + a_n \leq 1 + \cdots + 1 = n
$$
(if we add up $n$ things, each of which is at most $1$, the largest number we can get is $n$). So, we have shown
$$
n + 1 \leq n
$$
This implies $1 \leq 0$, which is absurd.

Comment: Note that, in my opinion, we didn't really *prove* anything. We just said the same thing in a different way and claimed we obviously reached a contradiction. We didn't start from any kind of definition, so the best we could do was move from intuition to intuition. If you want to read about how to more rigorously develop this and related ideas, you should google "cardinality."

Comment: would this be better done using induction then?

Comment: There certainly are some hidden proofs by induction in my argument. Any time you see $\cdots$ in math, that's a proof by induction that someone was either too lazy to do or had already done. That said, if I wanted to formalize this problem, I would say it like this: if there exists an injection $f : A \to B$ but there does not exist a bijection $g : A \to B$, prove that there does not exist an injection $h : B \to A$. In full generality, this is equivalent to the theorem of Cantor Schroeder and Bernstein about cardinalities. But I think the finite case can be handled by induction.